# How do i do a update query using concatenate in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I tried to run this query in SQL server:

```
update ABC set data = concat(data, 'a');
```

this returns: concat is not a built in function

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your database is in compatibility level 110, otherwise you can use the old style concat:

```
UPDATE ABC
SET data = data + 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
update [ABC] set data = data + 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update ABC 
 set data = ISNULL(data, '') + 'a';
```

**OR**

```
update ABC 
 set data = COALESCE(data, '') + 'a';
```